# Can't create Team project in tfs 2012 using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, team-project

I install TFS 2012 and I have visual studio 2010. I already create team collection but I can't create team project. Error message {you don't have permission create team project} but I give all permission to current user.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the Administration activities will not work when you are using lower version of Team Explorer client. You need to install Team Explorer 2012 or Visual Studio 2012 to create new team projects.

Comment: So if my only option is to use VS 2010 Professional, can I not use TFS 2012 express?