# Unable to create new project in TFS2012 from VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm at a loss.

I've installed a fresh instance of SQL Server Express 2012, loaded a fresh install of TFS2012. I attempted to hook my copy of VS2010 and I can't create a new project.

I started [here](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html#tfs2012) and installed the service packs, the updates and the compatibility packages. I made myself an admin (of everything) from the TFS2012 console. When I go to to create a new project from the Team Explorer I get the `TF30172` error.

[image: Error]

My permission window

[image: permissionWindow]

I'm flummoxed. I just ran [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) again. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Visual Studio 2010 can connect to TFS 2012 for development activities, but cannot directly create team projects for 2012. In fact, many administrative tasks (create Team Projects, build definitions, etc) in 2012 don't work from a 2010-based Team Explorer.

The solution is to upgrade to VS2012 or later, or to install Team Explorer 2012 to create team projects while continuing to use VS2010 for development.

Sadly Microsoft doesn't really declare this anywhere so it can be hard to find the answer.

See also: [Can't create Team project in tfs 2012 using visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406400/cant-create-team-project-in-tfs-2012-using-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: I feel like I've looked at 100s of SO posts on this but I never saw that one.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 can't work on TFS 2012. Installing the latest VS.NET should solve this. Generally, the rule of thumb is, new versions are backwards compatible. So VS.NET 2010 can connect to 2010/2008/2005 etc. VS.NET 2012/13 can connect to 2013/2012/2010/2008/2005. But connecting from 2010 to 2012 won't work.